# SharePoint Server Getting WorkflowInstanceID with REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-rest-api

Company is using SharePoint Server 2013 and i'm trying to write a service for another application which people can track workflow status.

What i try is getting Workflow Instance ID with;

`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Library Name')/Items(5)?$select=WorkflowInstanceID` and there is no select for list item like `$select=WorkflowAssociations`. And there is no `$expand='workflowname'` option. Because workflow is not expandable.

but `WorkflowInstanceID` always returns null, even i got attached multiple workflows and all of them started and completed.

My main goal is creating URL like `/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx?List={ListGuid}&WorkflowInstanceID={WorkflowInstanceGuid}` so when people click this link, they can track the workflow steps.

I've also tried to use `Tasks` list with `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/Items`, but this list also doesn't return Task's associated list item's GUID or WorkflowInstanceID

Answer (score 0):

A SharePoint list should contain an hyperlink field with your workflow name. This field can be used to get the full URL to the workflow instance.

```
<<site url>>/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('<<list title>>')/Items(<<item id>>)
```

The above API endpoint will return all columns including workflow field with the URL value.

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for help. But that query is not returning any url or workflowid, it only returns `Esignature": 20,` which is workflow's name and current status id. Also `FieldValuesAsHtml` and `FieldValuesAsText` both are not store any workflow url.